# Citing in APALIKE style with only year in brackets

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf, apa-style, bibliographystyle

I need to have only year in brackets in my citations in the text. How can I achieve this using the APALIKE bibliography style? I'm using an apalike.bst file, too.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{apalike}
```

```
\begin{document}

This is an example of a paragraph with in-text
citations using the apa BibTeX style.
Here is a reference to a journal article with
a single author \cite{palmer1997music}, to a journal
article with two authors \cite{greer1986music} and
three authors \cite{greer1986music}, and to a book
with four authors \cite{ahmat2017central}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

I've also tried the following code in the preamble but it produces no difference as citation in the text:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib]{apalike}
```

I really want to keep my bibliography in apalike style as it is now. I just would like to modify the citation style in the text, namely to "TEXT TEXT (year)".

Comment: In order to have additional citation commands (for in-text and parenthetical citations), I'd recommend using biblatex-apa instead of apalike... it will also get you something much closer to the current APA reference standard. You can use \textcite{} for in-text citation: Author (Year), or if you load biblatex with the natbib option, you can use \citet{}.

Comment: @DanMacKinnon Thank you for your comment. So, I think you imply that it is not possible to keep the apalike style for the bibliography only and use a different citation style for the citations in the text? The challenge is that I really need to keep the apalike style for the bibliography. Do you happen to know if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found an answer by combining some commands. It is actually working for me but not sure how I managed to achieve this. Probably, there is some redundant code in there.

I've inserted the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib]{apalike}
```

In the document, I use \cite and the following code to generate my bibliography in apalike style:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{referencefile.bib}
```

Comment: You can remove the line `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib]{apalike}`. The options you are passing are `biblatex` options and unknown to `apalike` (`biblatex` is completely incompatible with both `apalike` and `natbib` and their BibTeX/`thebibliography`-based approach). But but more importantly, the `natbib` definitions are more comprehensive than `apalike`'s, so it is enough to load `natbib`.

Comment: Technically speaking `\bibliography{referencefile.bib}` should be `\bibliography{referencefile}`, since `\bibliography` takes the file name without extension, but most modern systems will find the file even if you include the extension.